# Initialise variables (observables included) on Angular: Constructor, Declaration or ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

I have the following Angular component:

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  showComments: boolean = false;

  posts$: Observable<PostModel[]>;

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.posts$ = this.getPosts();

  }

  getPosts(): Observable<PostModel[]> {

    return this.postService.getRecentPosts();

  }

}
```

Should I define `posts$` inside the constructor?

That about `showComments` default value? Inside `ngOnInit` too?

If not, when should I use `ngOnInit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Constructor usage in Angular:**
In Angular, the constructor is used for injecting dependencies into the component class. Nothing much. And keep the constructor as simple as possible

**ngOnInit() method usage in Angular:**
Angular calls ngOnInit when it finishes creating a component DOM. And we will use constructors to inject all required dependencies and processed input bindings.

It’s a common practice to use ngOnInit to do actual work even though the logic doesn’t depend on DI, DOM or input bindings.